# Proof that every symmetric sequential relation on a non-empty set is an equivalence relation

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

Given the following proof:

A relation R on a non-empty set S is called *sequential* if for every element (x,y,z) in SxSxS, at least one of the ordered pairs (x,y) and (y,z) belongs to R. Prove or Disprove: Every symmetric sequential relation on a non-empty set is an equivalence relation.

Would I have to show that the relation R is both reflexive and transitive in order for the proof to be true?

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstand the definition, it seems to me that once the relation is sequential and symmetric, you have that $(x,y) \in R$ for *any* $x, y \in S$.  In other words, $R$ is a *total* relation: everything is related to everything! (and that makes $R$ trivially an equivalence relation)

Why?

Given that it is sequential, we have that for the element $(x,y,x) \in S \times S \times S$: either $(x,y) \in R$ or $(y,x) \in R$.  But given that it is symmetric, if one of these is in $R$, then the other is in $R$ as well.

Comment: Perhaps, it might be a useful exercise to think about what else might be possible if the sequentiality condition only applies to triples $(x,y,z)$ where $x\ne z$, or where all three elements are distinct.